# SQL Server 2008 update table from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008. I have 2 tables `AP_APO_HEAD` and  `AP_APO_HEAD_USRPED` and I want to update from table `AP_APO_HEAD_USRPED` column name `USR_PED_CHAR8` with results from table `AP_APO_HEAD` and column name `EID_PERIGR`.

With the following code I am getting `NULL` results, what is wrong?

```
UPDATE AP_APO_HEAD_USRPED
SET USR_PED_CHAR8 = t1.EID_PERIGR
FROM AP_APO_HEAD_USRPED 
INNER JOIN AP_APO_HEAD t1 ON AP_APO_HEAD_USRPED.KPP_APO_CODE = t1.KPP_APO_CODE  
WHERE t1.KPP_APO_CODE = '2'
GO
```

Comment: Your logic is OK...so the problem is certainly data related...See SQLFIDDLE : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f149b/3/4

Answer (score 0):

Please run this query and confirm if your are getting any rows, 
if you are not getting any result then this means there are no rows in table AP_APO_HEAD_USRPED with KPP_APO_CODE=2 and thats why you are getting NULL.

```
select * from AP_APO_HEAD_USRPED where KPP_APO_CODE='2'
```

Comment: i get 22561 results and the KPP_APO_CODE is the key which connects all the tables, the problem is that i get results but empty results

Comment: What do you mean by empty results? can you run the following query and show the data : select EID_PERIGR FROM AP_APO_HEAD  WHERE KPP_APO_CODE='2'

Comment: EID_PERIGR
--------------------------------------------------


 EVDERMIA PALMOGEN SOFT GELx30 
 ΠΑΡΑΦΑΡΜΑΚΕΥΤΙΚΟ 23%
05.00032 ΣΩΛΗΝΑΡΙΑ VENOJECT 1,
09.0137 ΓΑΝΤΙΑ ΜΙΑΣ ΧΡΗΣΗΣ LAR
22.00031 ΚΡΙΚΟΦ.ΣΤΥΛΕΟΙ/20Τ-1Λ
3035 ΠΛΑΣΤΙΚΟΣ ΚΟΦΤΗΣ ΚΑΛΩΝ
3M ΤΑΙΝΙΑ ΑΘΛΗΤΩΝ 3.75X10

Comment: Please run this query and let me know if you are getting any result: select t1.EID_PERIGR
FROM AP_APO_HEAD_USRPED 
INNER JOIN AP_APO_HEAD  t1 ON AP_APO_HEAD_USRPED.KPP_APO_CODE = t1.KPP_APO_CODE  
WHERE t1.KPP_APO_CODE = '2'

Comment: is it logical solution to make a temporary table with results from AP_APO_HEAD and then use this table to update AP_APO_HEAD_USRPED?

Comment: Yes, that is logical, but why you want to do that when you can update the table directly.

Comment: because i get as result empty result

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36341/discussion-between-sonam-and-babis-papadopoulos)